# React useState hook isn't updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am experiencing an issue with useState. Below is the code running in codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmznl0345r

Here is the code itself;

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

type FormElem = React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>;

interface ITodo {
  text: string;
  complete: boolean;
}

export default function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[]>([]);

  const handleSubmit = (e: FormElem): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo(value);
    setValue("");
  };

  const addTodo = (text: string): void => {
    const newTodos: ITodo[] = [...todos, { text, complete: false }];
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  const completeTodo = (index: number): void => {
    const newTodos: ITodo[] = todos;
    newTodos[index].complete = !newTodos[index].complete;
    setTodos(newTodos);
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={value}
          onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
      </form>
      <section>
        {todos.map((todo: ITodo, index: number) => (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <div>{todo.text}</div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => completeTodo(index)}>
              {" "}
              {todo.complete ? "Incomplete" : "Complete"}{" "}
            </button>
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

When the complete button is clicked it only runs the `completeTodo` function once, and it doesn't run again even though the setTodos function is run and the todos are updated.

This used to work in `react 16.7.0-alpha-2` but now with version `16.8.1` it seems not to update.

Let me know any suggestions you have, and once again here is the code running in codesandbox;

https://codesandbox.io/s/kmznl0345r

Comment: I believe this broke in 16.8 due to this change: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/14569. In `completeTodo`, `newTodos === todos` is `true` even after the change, because you're mutating the same array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently mutating the `todo` object in your `completeTodo` function. If you instead create a new array with all the elements in `todos` and create a new object where `complete` is toggled it will work as expected.

```
const completeTodo = (index: number): void => {
  const newTodos: ITodo[] = [...todos];
  newTodos[index] = {
    ...newTodos[index],
    complete: !newTodos[index].complete
  };
  setTodos(newTodos);
};
```